# Executing code after manually firing an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I'm manually creating and dispatching events to the DOM via createEvent and dispatchEvent...

it seems to work fine.

However, I'm firing multiple events and I need code to execute between them.

If I understand correctly (my background is in server programming), browsers place the event in a queue, which then executes in a background thread.

so if I do work in the foreground I could complete BEFORE the event executes.

Which I think I'm seeing.

.. so my work around is to dispatchEvent... then place a new function via setTimeout(callback,0) ...

the callback in timeout should execute AFTER the event..  correct?

Then I can just make my whole algorithm use callbacks.

do I have this right?

Comment: Just bind an event handler to whatever custom events you are firing. Btw, `createEvent` is deprecated.